# linking to root level then images folder

Tags: css, html

I have a file structure that looks like this:

[my site structre http://retailsitecommon.afstores.com/Develop/FreshMarket/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-02%20at%2012.12.00%20PM.png](http://retailsitecommon.afstores.com/Develop/FreshMarket/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-02%20at%2012.12.00%20PM.png)

I am trying to use root-level links for my images because I have a footer that needs to be used in subfolders of subfolders that has images in it. For instance, in my styles.css file I am trying background: url('/images/logo.png') no-repeat;, but the image doesn't show up. If I do background: url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat;, the image appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your site at the root level? Post the absolute URL of an image file.

Comment: Yeah, I just came to this conclusion also. I am working on a development server and so it is not at the root at this moment. However, why does it not work on my local copy?

Comment: Are you actually hosting the site locally or is it sitting in a folder somewhere? If so, `/` refers to the root of your hard drive.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Is there an easy way to "hack" this behavior since I don't have a domain where I can put these files at the root level (this is a redesign of a site so I can't put it at the root of the existing domain)?

Comment: Install a webserver. You don't need a domain name to host websites. Nor do you need to be connected to the internet.

Comment: Thank you so much Blender. You are a life saver, not to mention saving a portion of my sanity!

Answer (score 1):

I think this would need to be on a server to work like you would like. Try setting up Lamp on PC or Mamp on Mac.

Comment: On a Mac, Apache is installed by default — just need to start it up.

Answer (score 0):

Parent folder for files called from `.css` file is those where `.css` file is located. 
When you start file location with (back)slash, you redirect this file to thee file root.

It means:

```
/folder-in-root/
./folder-visible-from-stylesheet-file-location/
```